# Interview on Garbage Collection in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was recently asked a question on Garbage Collection in JAVA. It goes like-if I have three variable (say), a,b,c as shown below.
Then in what order these will be Garbage Collected.

```
class Test{

static String a;

private String b;

Test(String a, String b)

{
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
}

void disp(){

    System.out.println(a+" "+ b);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    String c="Not you Again";
    Test t= new Test("Hello","World");

    t.disp();
    System.out.println("Value of c = "+c);
}

}
```

I am aware of the Garbage Collection basics like Young Gen, Middle Gen & Perm Gen and how the objects are moved among them and collected. But Garbage Collection on Variables is something I am alien to.
Please help!

Comment: **Variables** are not garbage collected. **Objects** are garbage collected. Since all three variables are of the primitive type `int` (which is not an object), this question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @SarveshGupta an `int` is not an object. it can not be garbage collected.

Comment: how this: `this.a=a;` is right?

Comment: @Edwin it's perfectly OK, but you'll get a compile warning for a non-static reference to a static field.

Comment: @1bluestone thanx for pointing out my mistake, I have updated the question. Please suggest a suitable answer.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I don't think so. The code's perfectly Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values referenced by `Test.a`, `t.b` or `c` won't ever be garbage collected, because they're all still in scope when `main` finishes running.  That is, the VM exits without garbage collecting them.

As for the parameters `a` and `b` in the `Test` constructor, they could possibly be garbage collected, but it's very unlikely.  This particular program is going to finish far too quickly for the garbage collector to even start.

Comment: The second paragraph is nonsense. The parameters of the `Test` constructor are local variables and variables don’t get garbage collected at all. *Objects* get garbage collected and the objects which were referenced by the constructor parameters are still referenced by other variables which are, as your first paragraph already said, still in scope. Your answer started so good with referring to “*the values referenced by* `Test.a`, `t.b` or `c`…” and then has that contradicting second paragraph speaking about the collection of *parameters*, which are not values, but references.

Comment: @Holger I think the meaning in the second paragraph is clear - it's the objects referenced by those parameters that could (but probably don't) get garbage collected.

Comment: well, in that case, it’s dead wrong, as these objects are, as said, the same objects that you are correctly stating as not collectible in the first paragraph. That’s exactly the problem with saying nonsensical things like “parameters…could possibly be garbage collected”, as parameter can not get collected, only objects can, and these specific objects can *not* get collected.

Answer (score 1):

All three string variables will be garbage-collected when the VM damn pleases, if it ever damn pleases, and nobody has any control over that. Anyone claiming that they know when or even if these strings will be garbage-collected is lying.

Comment: I said somewhat same but he said will the static and private qualifiers not affect there collection.

Comment: Since the static members are stored in perm gen area would they not be the last to be collected.  Help Please!

Comment: @Sarvesh Gupta: to put it simple, this is bullshit. As already said in [this first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207618/interview-on-garbage-collection-in-java#comment77381302_45207618), variables are not garbage collected, objects are. And since an object can be referenced by an arbitrary number of variables of different kinds, the type of the variable is entirely irrelevant. The memory location of an object doesn’t suddenly change, when you store a reference to it in a `static` variable. In Java 8, there isn’t even a perm gen area.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collector will never run in this particular example.
Garbage collector runs only when there is no active thread alive, in this example there is no  dead thread thus, garbage collector will never run.
 Garbage collector is activated by JVM only and we cannot control it, although we can just make a request to run it,this request can be ignored by JVM.